# How to make sure try/except loop doesn't execute everything if an exception occurs?

Tags: python, try-catch, try-except

Let's say I have this code:

```
def my_func():
    print("Hello World")  # <-- This should work
    print(x)  # <-- This should NOT work, since x is undefined


try:
    my_func()
    # However, in my try-except loop, the function is being partially executed. 
    # I want it so that if there is an error, the function shouldn't execute at all, and nothing should happen
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

What I want to happen, is to execute the function, but if an error occurs, don't execute the function at all. I don't know if this is possible for a `try/except` loop because the intention of that is to execute code until there is an error, but there might be some other loop that can achieve this.
Apologies, I know this is a very beginner question, and that I should probably know this, but I am self-taught and never came across this and don't know what to do to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: How will it know if there is an error without running  it?

Comment: In theory, it is not possible. You will have to redesign the program, for example, implement some check before executing the function instead of `try/except`

Comment: `try`/`except` isn't a "loop".

Comment: `try`/`except` is to handle `Exception`s that occur when executing the code _between_ them — so what you ask makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, just wondering if this was possible. Thanks for all the helpful replies! I did think it would logically make sense that this wouldn't be possible, but, I don't know much about code, so I just wanted to know if it was possible. And, @KarlKnechtel, I honestly didn't know what to call it and a 'loop' sounded okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been stated what you want is not possible. What you can do however is structure the code in a different way so that x is required for the function to run:

```
def my_func(x):
    print("Hello World")
    print(x)

my_func(x)  # Will raise an error if x is not provided
```

Or, you can check any variables you need exist beforehand:

```
try:
    x
    # any other variable you need
    # this can also be done inside the function itself (probably better to do that tbh)
    my_func()

except NameError as e:
    print(e)
```

I know that the unassigned variable may not be the exact problem you're having but either way if you don't want the function to do something important and fail halfway, run some checks before hand, even just inside the function itself, to make sure it has the best chance of finishing. Hope this helps in some way, sorry if it's not what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Your answer and all the comments really helped out!